How do I merge audio using pulseaudio on ubuntu
Need to merge the inputs of microphone and audio coming over say google meet via chrome and then redirect this combined audio to a program and then send the audio output of the program on to the headphones and the browser(google meet).
I looked at this https://askubuntu.com/questions/388570/how-do-i-route-the-output-of-a-single-program-to-a-mic-input
but its not what I need.
This is for ubuntu 22.04 with pavucontrol
Thanks in advance.
Ajay
